# Saving deeply nested objects using subsquid

Tags: indexing, subsquid

I'm trying to save some deeply nested information to the database, but I keep encountering an error when I go to save it using `ctx.store.save(obj)`.

My object looks like this.

```
let writeToDB = {
    prop1: [],
    prop2: [ objA, objB],
    prop3: [ obj1, Obj2 ],
    prop4: 10,
    prop5: "astring",
    doesNotWork: {
      nestObj1: {
        field1: "aStringasdf",
        field2: {
          inceptionString1: "squid",
          inceptionString2: "shrimp"
        }
      },
      nestObj2: {
        ponds1: "anotherString",
        ponds2: {
          peach: "a",
          pear: "b",
          plumb: "c",
          apples: "d",
          bananas: "e",
          apricot: "f",
          oranges: "g"
        }
      }
    },
    pending: false,
    id: "15a56da27d-WG"
}
```

Where i'm having issues is when writing this nested object to the database.

```
doesNotWork: {
  nestObj1: {
    field1: "aStringasdf",
    field2: {
      inceptionString1: "squid",
      inceptionString1: "shrimp"
    }
  },
  nestObj2: {
    ponds1: "anotherString",
    ponds2: {
      peach: "a",
      pear: "b",
      plumb: "c",
      apples: "d",
      bananas: "e",
      apricot: "f",
      oranges: "g"
    }
  }
},
```

I generate my entity. (all extrinsic data are of type string,  int and boolean).

processor.ts file:

```
let ctx: ExtrinsicHandlerContext = ctxHandler; 

const extrinsicData = getExtrisic(ctx); //writeToDB  object
const entity = await getOrCreate(ctx.store, DesiredObject, id); //

entity.doesNotWork = extrinsicData.doesNotWork

ctx.store.save(entity);
```

When I build my code and run `processor.ts`, at the point it gets to save this object. I run into the error.

terminal: when running `node -r dotenv/config lib/processor.js`

```
  TypeError: obj.toJSON is not a function
    at Object.to (/path/squid-template/lib/model/generated/desiredObj.model.js:103:94)
    at Function.ApplyValueTransformers.transformTo (/path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/util/ApplyValueTransformers.js:22:28)
    at PostgresDriver.preparePersistentValue (/path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.js:517:69)
    at /path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:454:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:432:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.createValuesExpression (/path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:431:23)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.createInsertExpression (/path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:265:37)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.getQuery (/path/squid-template/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.js:38:21
```

going to /lib/model/generated/desiredObj.model.js:103:94

```
__decorate([
    (0, typeorm_1.Column)("jsonb", { transformer: { to: obj => obj == null ? undefined : obj.toJSON(), from: obj => obj == null ? undefined : new _properties_1.Properties(undefined, obj) }, nullable: true }),
    __metadata("design:type", Object)
], desiredObject.prototype, "doesNotWork", void 0);
```

I'm not too familiar with using GraphQL ORM, but I can see the toJSON function defined.... I've isolated the problem to the writing of this deep nested field. When I remove this property (incoming extrinsic data is null) it writes to the db. When it has data, it throws the typeError above.

Either there is something wrong with my schema (most likely) or it's a little deeper.

Any ideas? I tried getting this to work for a while now. How would you write the schema for the doesNotWork property? Assuming nullables for all nested fields? I've put my schema below for it.

Cheers

```
  type writeToDB @entity{
      prop1: [String]
      prop2: [XYZ] @derivedFrom(field: "ignore")
      prop3: [ABC] @derivedFrom(field: "these")
      prop4: Int!
      prop5: String!
      doesNotWork: DoesNotWork 
      pending: Boolean!
      id: ID!
  }
  
  type DoesNotWork {
    nestObj1: Object1 
    nestObj2: Object2 
  }
  
  type Object2 {
    ponds1: String
    ponds2: Fruits 
    pointerPropsA: DoesNotWork 
  }
  
  type Object1 {
    field1: String
    field2: InceptionObj 
    pointerPropsB: DoesNotWork 
  }
  
  
  type InceptionObj {
    inceptionString1: String 
    inceptionString1: String
    pointerProp1: Object1
  }
  
  type Fruits {
    peach: String
    pear: String
    plumb: String
    apples: String
    bananas: String
    apricot: String
    oranges: String
    pointerProp2: Object2
  }
```

Comment: Also, I just realized, this may be a TypeORM issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, I got it.

In the end, it was an issue with my schema.

I had to change it to this.

```
  type writeToDB @entity{
  prop1: [String]
  prop2: [XYZ] @derivedFrom(field: "ignore")
  prop3: [ABC] @derivedFrom(field: "these")
  prop4: Int!
  prop5: String!
  doesNotWork: DoesNotWork **@derivedFrom(field:"thisWorks")**
  pending: Boolean!
  id: ID!


 }
  
  type DoesNotWork **@entity** {
    nestObj1: Object1 
    nestObj2: Object2 
    thisWorks: **writeToDB! @unique**
  }
  
  type Object2 {
    ponds1: String
    ponds2: Fruits 
    pointerPropsA: DoesNotWork 
  }
  
  type Object1 {
    field1: String
    field2: InceptionObj 
    pointerPropsB: DoesNotWork 
  }
  
  
  type InceptionObj {
    inceptionString1: String 
    inceptionString1: String
    pointerProp1: Object1
  }
  
  type Fruits {
    peach: String
    pear: String
    plumb: String
    apples: String
    bananas: String
    apricot: String
    oranges: String
    pointerProp2: Object2
  }
```